# Show that if  is uniformly distribution between 0 and 1 and  = (1 −  )^-1, then  has the same distribution function as .

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

Question is as titled.

So  was given by a previous question, the following probability density function which I've worked out, hopefully correctly.

\begin{array}ff_X(x)= \begin{cases} ^{-2} \ \ \ \geqslant \ 1, & \\0\ \ \ \ \ \ < \ 1. & \end{cases}\end{array}

I was asked to find the distribution function of X. So i gave it a go to work it out which I hope the answer below is correct, pdf-to-cdf transformation

\begin{array}\$\int_1^x    t^{-2} dt   =  \frac{\mathrm{1} }{\mathrm{1}} - \frac{\mathrm{1} }{\mathrm{x}} = \frac{\mathrm{x-1} }{\mathrm{x}}\end{array}
\begin{array}wwhere : x  \geq 1\end{array}

From what I gathered from the question,  is a uniform distribution that can be expressed like this:  ∼  (0, 1). This is a continious problem

What I can understand from the question is that the uniform distribution will have a probability of 1 between the values 0 and 1: \begin{array} 00\leq x \leq 1 \end{array}

My guess is the question wants me to find out whether: \begin{array} YY = (1 - W)^{-1}\end{array} equals the same as the above limit. I am not 100% sure. I did some research into probability transformations as i believe thats what my question is asking but didnt get to helping me solve this question.

The question was taken from my statistics coursework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remember that, with a monotonic transformation $g$, you get

$$f_Y(y)=f_X[g^{-1}(y)]\Bigg|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\Bigg|$$

thus being

$$Y=\frac{1}{1-W}$$

you get $W=1-\frac{1}{Y}$ and obviously

$$f_Y(y)=1\cdot\Big|\frac{dw}{dy}\Big|=\frac{1}{y^2}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[1;+\infty)}(y)$$

This because

1. $f_W(w)=1$ and thus also $f_W[g^{-1}(y)]=1$
2. $\Bigg|\frac{d}{dy}(1-\frac{1}{y})\Bigg|=\frac{1}{y^2}$

(same density and thus same distribution as $X$)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would you able to elaborate on how you got the last equation? Cheers.

Comment: @OJL : $f_W(w)=1$ because $W\sim U(0;1)$ thus the result is simply the derivative. Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Comment: Yep all done. Thanks for the input ,was very helpful